# overall HIGH CPU utilization, but top is not showing process which is contributing to that spike

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Below is the output of a top command, which is showing "57.6%us, 24.0%sy" overall cpu utilization at a particular moment, but there is no process which is contributing to this spike of cpu usage.

What else could be contributing to this high cpu utilization? and how could I know the exact processes causing this high cpu?

I see >10000 context switches in vmstat, will that contribute to this high cpu?

### TOP:

```
top - 22:56:25 up 808 days, 20:16,  1 user,  load average: 1.96, 1.80, 1.69
Tasks:  70 total,   2 running,  68 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 57.6%us, 24.0%sy,  1.3%ni, 15.6%id,  0.0%wa,  0.1%hi,  1.3%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   2076108k total,   682120k used,  1393988k free,        0k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,   142888k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                                                                              
 2201 root      -2   0 88000 8608 5812 S  3.8  0.4  24481:27 process1                                                                                                                                               
 1393 root      20   0 81168 9888 1252 S  1.9  0.5  50250:12 process2                                                                                                                                              
16291 admin     20   0  2616  984  808 R  1.9  0.0   0:00.02 top                                                                                                                                                  
    1 root      20   0  3500  748  660 S  0.0  0.0   0:06.69 init                                                                                                                                                 
    2 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd                                                                                                                                             
    3 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0  20:06.23 ksoftirqd/0
```

VMSTAT:

```
vmstat 1 10                              
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- --system-- -----cpu------
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 4  0      0 1388252      0 148352    0    0     0     0    1    1 23 16 61  0  0
 4  0      0 1388124      0 148352    0    0     0     0  346 11694 74 26  0  0  0
 2  0      0 1388124      0 148352    0    0     0     0  366 12919 74 26  0  0  0
 2  0      0 1388252      0 148352    0    0     0     0  364 12910 67 33  0  0  0
 1  0      0 1388252      0 148352    0    0     0     0  350 11537 72 28  0  0  0
 2  0      0 1388252      0 148352    0    0     0     0  360 13018 73 27  0  0  0
 1  0      0 1388252      0 148352    0    0     0     0  352 12476 77 23  0  0  0
 3  0      0 1388124      0 148352    0    0     0     0  352 12354 79 21  0  0  0
```

Comment: How come it is normal? we are reaching ~58% of user space + 24% system cpu utilization, but out of 2 running process it is showing contribution only 3.8% and 1.9% respectively. Then who else is contributing to this cpu utilization, any contributur should be listed in this output right?

Comment: I can only suggest posting a complete `top` output and looking at that. Because as you see in your current posted output there are two running processes and you are showing just one (1) here in the output and one process you are adding in is sleeping. Find the missing running process and look for the CPU usage.

Comment: All other process are showing 0% cpu utilization and they are in S state.